# Umlaute not shown when hmtlspecialchars with UTF8 in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8

I have a problem that I couldn't figure out so far and I'd appreciate any help.

I have the following simple code:

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8");

$body .= "begrüßen zu dürfen";

echo htmlentities($body);
echo htmlentities($body, ENT_COMPAT,'UTF-8');

?>
```

The first echo works while the second returns an empty string. Why does this happen?

The variable $body is a combination of a fixed string like "`begrüßen zu dürfen`" and some text that comes from a mysql database with UTF-8. If I want to display the text from the DB correctly, let's call it $data, I need to use `htmlentities($data, ENT_COMPAT,'UTF-8');`, so I was thinking that I can use `htmlentities($body, ENT_COMPAT,'UTF-8')` to display the whole combined text (partly from DB and partly from a fixed string). However, this does not work.

Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: Is your file saved in UTF-8? Since the fixed string is the one that's not working, it's very likely your php file actually isn't saved in UTF-8

Comment: No it was in cp1252 (whatever this is :) ). If I do this, and use htmlentities($body, ENT_COMPAT,'UTF-8') it shows now some strange characters such as ��. Also if I change the filecode to UTF-8 then in the eclipse text editor it shows the "ü" as strange characters. Is there a way such that in eclipe I can type as usual ü but then on the web-page it is shown correctly and works fine together with some utf-8 encoded data from the DB when concatenated? Many thanks!

Comment: Listen to what we all say, convert your file to UTF8. That will fix your problems m8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must save your php file in UTF-8, not in CP1252.

To test you are doing it correctly, try:

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8");
die("öäå");
```

If this shows up strange characters, the file in question was not saved in UTF-8 properly.

Note that if you are using UTF-8 properly, you do not need to use htmlentities.

Comment: die works correctly but if I do htmlentities it does not work, neither with parameter 'UTF-8' (when it shows nothing), nor without (when it shows strange character)

Comment: @user1513073 if your motivation to use `htmlentities` is to escape html, you should be using `htmlspecialchars`. If you cannot support UTF-8 at all, you should use `htmlentities` which can encode any unicode code point with ASCII characters. But you since you can use UTF-8 I do not see a reason for using htmlentitites at all.

Comment: The reason is that I use htmlentities because later I combine my fixed string with a text that I get from a database in utf-8. And this text is only displayed correctly when I use htmlentities(...,"UTF-8"). Sorry for my confusion... this UTF-8 stuff is just extremely confusing for me :)

Comment: @user1513073 if you have a utf8 fixed string (file was saved in utf-8), and you combine it with a string from database, and it doesn't work, the database didn't actually give you utf8 string. Or you are using PHP functions that don't understand utf-8 and corrupt the string (Such as `subtsr`).  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through

Comment: How can I figure out if the DB gives me UTF-8? Before I do a query I make a call $mysql->exec("set names 'utf8'") so I thought that all data shall arrive in the format. Notice that when I print such data I always get strange characters unless I use the UTF-8 format 
together with htmlentities or htmlspecialchars. The only string operation I use is concatenation, i.e., .
The strange thing is that when I use ENT-IGNORE optione, then it works all over sudden.

Comment: @user1513073 do the same quick test, except `die($string_from_mysql_that_has_umlauts);` It's probably good thing to get to the bottom of this and understand the real cause.

Comment: Yes, I think so too. I tried what you suggested with the die and it works fine, so I am still not sure what is the reason for this behavior. Also, why does the approach of DarkXphenomenon work?
I'd appreciate a lot your suggestions.

Comment: @user1513073 if you verified using the `die` method that database sends you utf8 strings and your files are saved as utf8, then that leaves interaction with the strings. As I noted before, many php functions corrupt utf8 strings. You should see if you are doing anything with the strings. if you simply `echo $database_string.$hard_coded_string` it should work. His method works because he is making the function ignore invalid code sequences, but there should be no invalid code sequences in the first place.

Comment: It was a str_replace apparently...thanks again for your valuable help!

Comment: @user1513073 yeah that one can corrupt utf-8 strings because it's not aware of utf-8. You should use mb extension in general with internal encoding set to utf8. Here's more http://php.net/manual/en/book.mbstring.php

Answer (score 1):

The second case returns a blank string because it encounters "invalid code unit sequences" in that string. The following does work and returns everything except the unicode characters.

```
echo htmlentities($body, ENT_QUOTES | ENT_IGNORE ,"UTF-8");
```

[ENT_IGNORE](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) silently discard invalid code unit sequences instead of returning an empty string.

The reason you are encountering invalid sequences is because the encoding for your php-file is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

Check if your file is saved as UTF8, this works for me just right:

```
header( "Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8" );
$body = "begrüßen zu dürfen";
echo htmlentities( $body );
```

Output:

```
begrüßen zu dürfen
```